# OpenId Connect Authentication Properties

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

In my application I am redirecting users to an Azure B2C screen so they can make a change to their account.

I pass the user to B2C using the following code, which includes a reference to `properties.Items`, which I am populating with a value:

```
var scheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl };

properties.Items["data1"] = "[possiblySensitiveData]";

return Challenge(properties, scheme);
```

When the user returns from the Azure B2C screen to my application, I can then retrieve the value from `data1`.

Is it possible that someone listening in could also retrieve the value stored in ``data1```? Or are any values passed in this way encrypted by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OpenIdConnectHandler` encrypts the data: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/78ab4bd673c1040cf59400be76daf395062bc6a7/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs#L450.

```cs
message.State = Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(properties);
```

This data protector is setup here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectPostConfigureOptions.cs#L46-L48.

```cs
var dataProtector = options.DataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(
    typeof(OpenIdConnectHandler).FullName!, name, "v1");
options.StateDataFormat = new PropertiesDataFormat(dataProtector);
```

It uses the standard Data Protection system in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Thanks, that's the confirmation I was after. I don't want to expose anything which shouldn't be.